# how to get value of primefaces calendar in managed bean?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i have a calendar in my jsf page that i want to get his value when its changed i tryed to add listener but didnt work i found other solutions but didnt work with primefaces 3.5:

```
   <p:calendar id="popupButtonCal22" value="#{zp01ManagedBean.datedeplanification}" showOn="button" locale="fr"  >
<p:ajax listener="#{zp01ManagedBean.setDatedeplanification(zp01ManagedBean.datedeplanification)}"/>   
                </p:calendar>
```

do you know how to fixe this problem ?

i am using primefaces 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to set the value manually by an ajax listener, as the setter is implicitly called when the value of the field is submitted. All you have to do is to submit the value on change. So try this:

```
<p:calendar id="popupButtonCal22" value="#{zp01ManagedBean.datedeplanification}" showOn="button" locale="fr"  >
    <p:ajax process="popupButtonCal22" partialSubmit="true" event="change"/>   
</p:calendar>
```

If you would additionally like to call an action after the value changed you can add `listener="#{someBean.someAction"` to the `p:ajax`-tag.

And if you would like to do some checks with the old and the new value use the `valueChangeListener`-attribute of the `p:calendar`-tag.

Comment: i still have the same problem i get null from "datedeplanification" in the managed bean. i want just get the date value chosed but still have Null value.

Answer (score 5):

- ```
  <p:ajax partialSubmit="true"/>
  ```

  works with inputText.
- ```
  <p:ajax event="dateSelect"/>
  ```

  works with calendar when is selected a date.
- ```
  <p:ajax event="change"/>
  ```

  works with calendar when is typed a date.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the `p:calendar` component in a `h:form` tag. I don't see why your code won't work actually, you do not even need ajax for that...

Comment: Post the code for your bean, I suspect something wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try This, May be this can Help:

```
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:calendar id="dateObj" value="#{test.date1}" showOn="button" pattern="dd-MMMM-yyyy">
            <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{test.handleDateSelect}"/>
        </p:calendar>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

The Bean is like that:

```
private Date date1;
public Date getDate1() {
    return date1;
}

public void setDate1(Date date1) {
    this.date1 = date1;
}


public void handleDateSelect(DateSelectEvent event){

    System.out.println(event.getDate());
}
```

Comment: When you select a date using `<p:calendar>` its always a dateSelect event and a handler in the backing Bean gets the date as soon as you select a date.Try this..If this what you wanted.

Comment: DateSelectEvent doesnt existe in primefaces 3.5 :(

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/wiki/MigrationGuide
as per this use SelectEvent instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p:calendar ...>
    <p:ajax event="dateSelect" ... />
    <p:ajax event="change" ... />
</p:calendar>
```

This works for me.